# Запись настроек Автокада (путей к инструментальным палитрам) в файл txt

Tags: lisp

Здравствуйте Уважаемые программисты!

Подскажите пожалуйста как кодом (Lisp Autocad2020) выполнить следующее:

1. Посмотреть какие пути к палитрам в настройках Автокада, т.е. "exPath",
2. Записать все эти пути в файл TXT с условием: исключить пути "C:\путь1" и "C:\путь2" (если таковые есть в "exPath") и исключить дублирование записей в TXT.

! В "exPath" пути (если их несколько) перечислены через ";". Лучше возможно при экспорте в txt заменить этот разделитель на переход на другую строку? Т.е. посмотреть 1-ое выражение до знака ";", затем 2-ое и т.д. В конце последнего выражения знака ";" нет.

Для примера:

- изначально "exPath" считывается так:
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\Autodesk\AutoCAD 2020\R23.1\rus\support\ToolPalette;c:\cad;c:\палитры;\server\палитры
- в txt можно вывести в виде списка (исключив определенные пути "C:\путь1" и "C:\путь2" и дублирование):
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\Autodesk\AutoCAD 2020\R23.1\rus\support\ToolPalette
  c:\cad
  c:\палитры
  \server\палитры

Заранее спасибо!

```
(setq exPath (vla-get-toolPalettePath (vla-get-files (vla-get-preferences (vlax-get-acad-object)))))
(setq path_list (list "C:\\путь1" "C:\\путь2"))

(if (setq file (open "C:\\MyPaths.txt" "a"))
  (progn
    (write-line exPath file)
    (close file)
  )
)
```